# HTML Input and create iFrame URL with user input?

Tags: html

How can I take my below prompt and use what the user types into the prompt and turn it into a iFrame URL like below:

```
<iframe src="http://www.weather.com" sandbox="" seamless="" width="100%" height="200 </iframe>


<html>
<head>
<script>
function disp_prompt()
 {
var sitename=prompt("Please enter your Website:","www.anywebsite.com")
document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML="Your Site: " + sitename
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="button" onclick="disp_prompt()" value="Click to enter in Website URL">
<br><br>

<div id="msg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you need to fully create an iframe element, or just replace scr attr in the existing?

Comment: just replace the SCR attr in the existing and submit to server. I also tried using <form name="input" action=""method="get">
Website URL: <input type="text" name="site">
<br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I guess what I am trying to do is just have an input box where I can type in the URL and then once I hit submit it will create the iframe. is this even possible with HTML?

Comment: Here is my site to give you an idea. http://test.joshualeethompson.com/node/7

Comment: optimized your code =)

Comment: @EL Thanks for all your help! When I click the Submit button inside the iframe window it doesnt change the site URL... Could it be a permission issue with writing to a page?

Comment: INSIDE THE IFRAME? That's a vast difference =)

Comment: try `top.document.getEle...` instead of `document.getEle..`

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<body>

<iframe id="iframeID" src="http://www.weather.com" sandbox="" seamless="" width="100%" height="200"></iframe>
    <form name="FormInput" action="" method="get" id="input" onsubmit="document.getElementById('iframeID').src=document.FormInput.site.value;">
 Website URL: 
<input type="text" name="site"/>
<br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
<br/>
</form>


<div id="msg"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works on Youtube, Vimeo

Hope it helps:

[click here to run the script](http://jsfiddle.net/RxeZd/)

```
function createIFrame(url, width, height){

switch(url.substring(7,12)){
    case "www.y":
        return url.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');       
        break;
    case "youtu":
         return url.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:youtube\.com|youtu\.be)\/(?:watch\?v=)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');       
        break;
    case "vimeo":
        return url.replace(/(?:http:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:vimeo\.com)\/(?:\/\?)?(.+)/g, '<iframe width="'+width+'" height="'+height+'" src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
        break;
}
```

}